# how can i target(change) the default CSS of mat paginator?

Tags: angular, types, angular-material, pagination, customization

I want to customize the css of  default paginator provided by angular material is there any way to target the css of paginator ??

::ng-deep is only able to target the outer container .
but when it comes to the pagesizeoption or next ,previous button class it is not workin!!

Comment: ::ng-deep .mat-paginator {
  /* your custom CSS */
}

Comment: what is the version of Angular you are using and what changes you are expecting?